# How to highlight something in one text so that it's highlighted in all other opened texts (Notepad++)?

Tags: notepad++, highlighting

If I am searching a whole process, in 2 opened texts and the process revolving between 1st text to 2nd text. When I am highlighting something in 1st document , it is not highlighted in 2nd text.

Is there any way that we highlight something on 1st text and it is visible on other opened texts too?

Comment: What is texts ?  tabs, files ?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

I am going to assume by "texts" you mean other tabs. I am going to assume by "highlighting" you mean bookmark.

The answer to the question is then; no.

If you look in the 'Mark' tab on the Find dialog, there is no `Find All in All Opened Documents`.

The closest you'll get is to put both sets of "texts" into 1 tab, or use Find with the `Find All in All Opened Documents` option to show you a search results panel at the bottom of the window.